# Printing an assosiative array sorted by key

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

i use this code to get info about friends

```
<?php   
 $fql = "SELECT uid, name, pic_square FROM user WHERE uid = me() OR uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ";

 $fUIDS = $facebook->api(array(
 'method' => 'fql.query',
 'query' =>$fql,
 ));
 print_r($response); 
?>
```

now i need to show the result in this way

```
echo '<img src="'.$response['pic_square'].'"/>';
```

but it did not worked so i did this

```
$fql = "SELECT pic_square FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) ";
$fPics = $facebook->api(array(
'method' => 'fql.query',
'query' =>$fql,
));

$i=count($fPics);
echo 'Total '.$i.' entries found !<br/>'; // this lines shows 10 as expected :)
for ($x=0;$x<$i;$x++)
 echo '<img src="'.$fPIcs[$x].'"/>';
```

now it shows `Array` **10 times**, what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When PHP prints `Array`, that means it tried to turn an array into a string.

It is very likely that `$fPics` is an array of arrays, not an array of strings.

Try calling `print_r($fPics)`, I bet you'll see that each element is actually an array with a single key, `pic_square`, and a single value -- the URL to the image, which is what you want.

If so, this means that your loop can be changed to reference that array element:

```
foreach($fPics as $row) {
    echo '<img src="', htmlspecialchars($row['pic_square']), '">';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

possibly it's cause thats is multidimensional array.
To make sure use following methods:
print_r, var_dump() or var_export()

Theres show your variable consist of.